# How to add BackgroundWorker for this code?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, backgroundworker

I've the following code, it's a code that parses an external Log file to a datagridview, however when I load a big file the operation takes time and the form freezes for a bit, what I need is to show a progress bar while it's parsing the log file.

This is the code :

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
        TextFieldParser(TextBox1.Text)
                Reader.TextFieldType =
                            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth

                Reader.SetFieldWidths(Convert.ToInt32(txtDate.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtTime.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtExt.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtCO.Text), _
                                     Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtDuration.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtAccCode.Text))
                Dim currentRow As String()
                While Not Reader.EndOfData
                    Try
                        currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
                        Dim currentField As String

                        For Each currentField In currentRow
                            Dim curRowIndex = dg1.Rows.Add()
                            ' Set the first cell of the new row....
                            dg1.Rows(curRowIndex).Cells(0).Value = currentRow(0)
                            dg1.Rows(curRowIndex).Cells(1).Value = currentRow(1)
                            dg1.Rows(curRowIndex).Cells(2).Value = currentRow(2)
                            dg1.Rows(curRowIndex).Cells(3).Value = currentRow(3)
                            dg1.Rows(curRowIndex).Cells(4).Value = currentRow(4)
                            dg1.Rows(curRowIndex).Cells(5).Value = currentRow(5)
                            dg1.Rows(curRowIndex).Cells(6).Value = currentRow(6)
                        Next

                    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                        MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                        "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                    End Try
                End While
                MsgBox("Total records imported : " & dg1.RowCount)
                lblTotal.Text = "Total Records: " & dg1.RowCount

            End Using
        Catch
            MsgBox("Invalid file, please make sure you entered the right path")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a BackgroundWorker and set its WorkerReportsProgressProperty to True.

Add a ProgressBar.

Then try this code out:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim widths() As Integer = { _
                Convert.ToInt32(txtDate.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtTime.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtExt.Text), _
                Convert.ToInt32(txtCO.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtDuration.Text), _
                Convert.ToInt32(txtAccCode.Text)}
            ProgressBar1.Visible = True
            ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee ' continuos animation 
            Dim input As New Tuple(Of String, Integer())(TextBox1.Text, widths)
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(input)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Width!")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim input As Tuple(Of String, Integer()) = DirectCast(e.Argument, Tuple(Of String, Integer()))
        Try
            Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(input.Item1)
                Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
                Reader.SetFieldWidths(input.Item2)
                Dim currentRow() As String
                While Not Reader.EndOfData
                    Try
                        currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
                        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(-1, New Object() { _
                            currentRow(0), currentRow(1), currentRow(2), _
                            currentRow(3), currentRow(4), currentRow(5), _
                            currentRow(6)})
                    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                        MessageBox.Show("Line is not valid and will be skipped." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
                    End Try
                End While
            End Using
        Catch
            MsgBox("Invalid file, please make sure you entered the right path")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        Dim values() As Object = DirectCast(e.UserState, Object())
        dg1.Rows.Add(values)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        MessageBox.Show("Total records imported : " & dg1.RowCount)
        lblTotal.Text = "Total Records: " & dg1.RowCount
        ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it's now adding only one field to the 1st column and the value is System.Object[]

Comment: I updated the ProgressChanged() event...see if that's any better.